# Find the sum of array using multiple threads that need cause race condition

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a program that uses multithreading to add a array from 1 to 1000, there are 5 threads in total, the result should be different every time, but I get the correct answer every time. How can I make  data inconsistency issue? I need to make it result race condition.

```
public class SyncDemo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new SyncDemo1().startThread(); //need something else beside the correct answer 500500

    }
    private void startThread() {
        int[] num = new int[1000];
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        MyThread thread1 = new MyThread(num, 1, 200);
        MyThread thread2 = new MyThread(num, 201, 400);
        MyThread thread3 = new MyThread(num, 401, 600);
        MyThread thread4 = new MyThread(num, 601, 800);
        MyThread thread5 = new MyThread(num, 801, 1000);
        executor.execute(thread1);
        executor.execute(thread2);
        executor.execute(thread3);
        executor.execute(thread4);
        executor.execute(thread5);
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

        }
        int temp = thread1.getSum() + thread2.getSum() + thread3.getSum() + thread4.getSum()+ thread5.getSum();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        int totalSum = temp;
        System.out.println(totalSum);
    }
    private static void pause() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    private static class MyThread implements Runnable {
        private int[] num;
        private int from , to , sum;
        public MyThread(int[] num, int from, int to) {
            this.num = num;
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            sum = 0;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
                sum += i;
            }
            pause();
        }
        public int getSum() {
            return this.sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.  You seem to have written perfectly correct code, that gives the correct answer.  Which wrong answer do you want, and why?

Comment: @Rex, I second what Dawood stated. If you are trying to cause the thread to collide, your code won't do that. You need to create a shareable resource and have the threads fight for it. That should yield the result you want. This code won't result in a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to experiment with race conditions, you can experiment using this demo class

```
class RaceConditionDemo implements Runnable {
    private int counter = 0;
    
    public void increment () {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        counter++;
    }
    
    public void decrement () {
        counter--;
    }
    
    public int getValue () {
        return counter;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run () {
        this.increment();
        System.out.println("Value for Thread After increment "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + this.getValue());

        this.decrement();
        System.out.println("Value for Thread at last "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + this.getValue());
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        RaceConditionDemo counter = new RaceConditionDemo();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(counter, "Thread-1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(counter, "Thread-2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(counter, "Thread-3");
        Thread t4 = new Thread(counter, "Thread-4");
        Thread t5 = new Thread(counter, "Thread-5");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
        t5.start();
    }
}
```

Here, the `Runnable` class contains a primitive `int` as a shared resource. As you may know, primitives are not thread-safe and pre-increment nor post-increment are atomic operations. Run enough times, and you will notice the values printed out are not predictable.

I feel weird posting this as an answer because your question seeks code that is implemented incorrectly. This is a first for me.

The output (of one of the runs)

```
Value for Thread After increment Thread-3 5
Value for Thread After increment Thread-5 5
Value for Thread After increment Thread-1 5
Value for Thread After increment Thread-2 5
Value for Thread at last Thread-2 1
Value for Thread After increment Thread-4 5
Value for Thread at last Thread-1 2
Value for Thread at last Thread-5 3
Value for Thread at last Thread-3 4
Value for Thread at last Thread-4 0
```

Notice how, sometimes, one thread executes it's `run()` method while another thread is still in the middle of the execution. So you may see `"Value for Thread After increment"` printed out consecutively before either one got a chance to execute the decrement and print out `"Value for Thread at last"`. This causes an instability in the value being printed out. In fact, it is possible that the value of the `counter` variable changes just before one thread finishes the increment or decrement.

Comment: Good example. Maybe for the benefit of future readers, it's worth to briefly mention what are the means we have to avoid race condition (namely Locks and Conditions).